# Limiting number of guesses in a Python guessing game

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and just starting to make a guessing game.

I finally managed to figure out a way to make the game work by allowing the user to try again if they run out of 3 guesses with this code (hopefully this is ok for you people)

```
from random import randint

random_number = randint(1, 10)
guesses_left = 3
guess = None
while True:
    print(f"You have {guesses_left} guseses left")
    guess = input("Pick a number between 1 and 10\n")
    guess = int(guess)
    if guess > random_number:
        print("Too high")
        guesses_left -= 1
    elif guess < random_number:
        print("Too low")
        guesses_left -= 1
    else:
        guesses_left = 3
        print("Good Job! You got it!")
        if input("Would you like to play again (y/n)\n") == "y":
            random_number = randint(1, 10)
        else:
            print("Thanks for Playing!")
            break
    if guesses_left == 0:
        guesses_left = 3
        print("You ran out of guesss :(")
        if input("Would you like another try?\n") != "y":
            print("Thanks for playing!")
            break
```

However before I got to that conclusion, I had the final if statement placed above the 2nd to last else statement (I probably didn't say that well but hopefully the code explains it) and the code didn't work in the end (It said I got the number right even if the number was wrong) Could someone help me explain why I need to put that block of code at the bottom instead of the final else statement?

```
from random import randint

random_number = randint(1, 10)
guesses_left = 3
guess = None
while True:
    print(f"You have {guesses_left} guseses left")
    guess = input("Pick a number between 1 and 10\n")
    guess = int(guess)
    if guess > random_number:
        print("Too high")
        guesses_left -= 1
    elif guess < random_number:
        print("Too low")
        guesses_left -= 1

    **if guesses_left == 0:
        guesses_left = 3
        print("You ran out of guesss :(")
        if input("Would you like another try?\n") != "y":
            print("Thanks for playing!")
            break**

    else:
        guesses_left = 3
        print("Good Job! You got it!")
        if input("Would you like to play again (y/n)\n") == "y":
            random_number = randint(1, 10)
        else:
            print("Thanks for Playing!")
            break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second code snippet, you are checking whether `guesses_left` is equals to 0. After the first guess, it isn't, and so it goes to the 'else', where `Good job, you got it!` is printed.

````py
    if guesses_left == 0:
        guesses_left = 3
        print("You ran out of guesss :(")
        if input("Would you like another try?\n") != "y":
            print("Thanks for playing!")
            break

    else:
        guesses_left = 3
        print("Good Job! You got it!")
    ```
````

Comment: When you put it so simply like that it actually makes a lot of sense now! Thank you also to the others who helped to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

The `if` at the same indent level after an `elif` starts a new set of branches; its evaluation is largely independent of the previous branches (the exception being any state change, such as the alteration of `guesses_left` in the sample). Consider what you have going into the block (in particular, the value of `guesses_left`:

```
if guesses_left == 0:
    guesses_left = 3
    print("You ran out of guesss :(")
    if input("Would you like another try?\n") != "y":
        print("Thanks for playing!")
        break
else:
    guesses_left = 3
    print("Good Job! You got it!")
    if input("Would you like to play again (y/n)\n") == "y":
        random_number = randint(1, 10)
    else:
        print("Thanks for Playing!")
        break
```

This connects to general design principles that can help avoid this sort of mistake: decompose a task into discrete subtasks and reduce [coupling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)). In this case, "check the guess" and "check for game end" are separate subtasks, which should reflect in the code (as was done in the final, working program). You can separate the tasks out into distinct functions, classes, modules or frameworks (as appropriate), but even if you don't, you can write your code in such a way as it can later be refactored into separate pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Hi The reason is when you inserted the if after your elif you had reinitated another condition. thus, the else follows the condition on the second if statement and not the first condition. see the below example

```
a = 3
b = 'a dsistraction'
if a ==3:
    print('yes 3')
elif a ==1:
    print('yes 1')
if b == 2:
    print('reseting the condition')
else:
    print('broken out of the first if')
#yes 3
#a followin
```

What you will realise is there are two different conditions. thus rather than use if, you are better off using an elif statement